# Count number of Item using Hibernate/JPA or JdbcTemplate

Tags: spring, hibernate, jpa

I am new to Spring/Hibernate/JPA. I have an entity class MovieEntity and MovieVersionEntity. MovieEntity has few details about the movie (like genre of movie) but MovieVersionEntity has more details about it (name, director...). So I want to count the number of movies (MovieVersionEntity) associated to the MovieEntity for the given type.

MovieEntity:

```
@Entity(name="MovieEntity")
@Table(name="Movie")
public class MovieEntity {

    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="Id")
    private long id;

    @Column(name="IsDeleted")
    private boolean isDeleted;

    @Column(name="ModifiedDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @OneToOne()
    @JoinColumn(name="MovieTypeId")
    private MovieTypeEntity movieTypeEntity;

    @OneToMany(mappedBy="movieEntity",optional = false)
    private List<MovieVersionEntity> movieVersionEntity;

    @Transient
    //@Formula("select count(*) from movie_version mv where mv.id=id")
    private int childCount;

    public long getId() {
        return id;
    }

    public void setId(long id) {
        this.id = id;
    }

    public boolean isDeleted() {
        return isDeleted;
    }

    public void setDeleted(boolean isDeleted) {
        this.isDeleted = isDeleted;
    }

    public MovieTypeEntity getMovieTypeEntity() {
        return movieTypeEntity;
    }

    public void setMovieTypeEntity(MovieTypeEntity movieTypeEntity) {
        this.movieTypeEntity = movieTypeEntity;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public MovieVersionEntity getMovieVersionEntity() {
        return movieVersionEntity;
    }

    public void setMovieVersionEntity(MovieVersionEntity movieVersionEntity) {
        this.movieVersionEntity = movieVersionEntity;
    }

    public int getChildCount() {
        return childCount;
    }

    public void setChildCount(int childCount) {
        this.childCount = childCount;
    }
}
```

MovieVersionEntity

```
@Entity(name = "MovieVersionEntity")
@Table(name="MovieVersion")
//@EntityListeners(AuditingEntityListener.class)
public class MovieVersionEntity {

    @Id()
    @GeneratedValue(strategy=GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(name="MovieId")
    private long movieId;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="MovieName")
    private String movieName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="DirectorName")
    private String directorName;

    @NotBlank
    @Column(name="Description")
    private String description;

    @Column(name="StopDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    private Date stopDate;

    @Column(name="DoneWatching")
    private boolean doneWatching;

    @Column(name="WatchDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    //@CreatedDate
    private Date watchDate;

    @Column(name="ModifiedDate")
    @Temporal(TemporalType.TIMESTAMP)
    //@LastModifiedDate
    private Date modifiedDate;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false)
    @JoinColumn(name="Id")
    private MovieEntity movieEntity;

    public String getMovieName() {
        return movieName;
    }

    public void setMovieName(String movieName) {
        this.movieName = movieName;
    }

    public String getDirectorName() {
        return directorName;
    }

    public void setDirectorName(String directorName) {
        this.directorName = directorName;
    }

    public String getDescription() {
        return description;
    }

    public void setDescription(String description) {
        this.description = description;
    }

    public Date getStopDate() {
        return stopDate;
    }

    public void setStopDate(Date stopDate) {
        this.stopDate = stopDate;
    }

    public boolean isDoneWatching() {
        return doneWatching;
    }

    public void setDoneWatching(boolean doneWatching) {
        this.doneWatching = doneWatching;
    }

    public Date getWatchDate() {
        return watchDate;
    }

    public void setWatchDate(Date watchDate) {
        this.watchDate = watchDate;
    }

    public Date getModifiedDate() {
        return modifiedDate;
    }

    public void setModifiedDate(Date modifiedDate) {
        this.modifiedDate = modifiedDate;
    }

    public long getMovieId() {
        return movieId;
    }

    public void setMovieId(long movieId) {
        this.movieId = movieId;
    }

    public MovieEntity getMovieEntity() {
        return movieEntity;
    }

    public void setMovieEntity(MovieEntity movieEntity) {
        this.movieEntity = movieEntity;
    }
}
```

I have written a query but I am getting sql error for it

```
@Query(value = "select m.*, ct.ChildCount" +
            "from (" +
            "select mv.id, count(movie_id) as ChildCount " +
            "from movie_version mv " +
            "group by mv.id" +
            ") as ct join movie m " +
            "on ct.id = m.id;",nativeQuery = true)
    List<MovieEntity> getMoviesWithCount();

Error
com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near 'select mv.id, count(movie_id) as ChildCount from movie_version mv group by mv.id' at line 1
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:422) ~[na:1.8.0_60]
    at com.mysql.jdbc.Util.handleNewInstance(Util.java:425) ~[mysql-connector-java-5.1.44.jar:5.1.44]
    at
```

Also, I am not sure if this is a right way to do it. Is there any other way I can save the count in the Transient variable. I tried using @Formuala too, but that does not give me 0 count.

Formula:
@Formula("select count(*) from movie_version mv where mv.id=id")

This is the first time I am dealing with Transient variable and I am not sure how it maps to the entity if its not persisted in the db.

Comment: You're using `List<MovieVersionEntity> movieVersionEntity;` in the `MovieEntity` class - why not take the length of that list? Or iterate over it for future use? Aren't these the childs you want to use in `childCount`?

Comment: @Query("select size(u.children) from Parent u where u.id=:parentID") int findAllChildrenCount(@Param("parentID")Long parentID); try this in your repository and change parent and child as per your class...

Comment: Yes. I can iterate through the list.  I was avoiding any type of calculation on the service side and wanted Hibernate to handle it. The List can grow and I do not want any kind of processing on my end.

Answer (score 0):

However, @Formula worked for me. @Transient and @Formula cannot go together. @Formula is read only so I do not have to worry about the data being persisted.

http://outbottle.com/hibernate-populating-an-unmapped-entity-field-with-count-using-formula/